# Symfony Gaufrette create a copy of an image

Tags: image, symfony, copy, filesystems, gaufrette

I'm using a Symfony Gaufrette for storing images in a filesystem. It works fine when I store an image first time. But I also need to create a copy of the image after it was uploaded to the filesystem. Is there any way to do it?

I use this function for writing:

```
$filesystem->write($imagepath, file_get_contents($answer->get('imageObject')->getData()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting all day long to make Gaufrette work with my Symfony2 app and Amazon S3 ... whenever I've made a step forward I had to take another fight ...

Finally I've switched to [Flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/) and all my problems were gone ...
It's much better written and it just works (although config is almost the same).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `copy()` method now is not implemented in `Gaufrette`(you can see it in [Adapter interface](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter.php)), so the only way to copy file using this library is to use `read()` and `write()` methods.